# How to apply code to only first iteration of loop

Tags: python, json, loops

I am trying to write a piece of code that appends the track['TrackConditionRating'] for all iterations, if the first iteration of 'RaceNumber' = 1. The problem with my current code is that is being applied broadly to all iterations. For example, it will not use track['TrackConditionRating'] if 'RaceNumber' = 6, even though the first iteration of 'RaceNumber' =1.

Example of JSON:

```
"TrackConditionHistory":[
   {
      "RaceNumber":1,
      "TrackConditionRatingSourceNumber":8,
      "TrackCondition":"Heavy",
      "TrackConditionRating":"Heavy 8",
      "TrackConditionRatingSource":8,
      "TrackConditionSource":5
   },
   {
      "RaceNumber":6,
      "TrackConditionRatingSourceNumber":9,
      "TrackCondition":"Heavy",
      "TrackConditionRating":"Heavy 9",
      "TrackConditionRatingSource":9,
      "TrackConditionSource":5
   }
]
```

My code:

```
for track in json['TrackConditionHistory']:
    raceno = track['RaceNumber']
    if not raceno == 1:
        trackcondition = json['TrackCondition']
    else:
        trackcondition = track['TrackConditionRating']
data.append((meetcode, raceno, trackcondition))
```

Comment: python has a function called index(), which returns the index (position) of an element in a list. Perhaps you can utilize that

Comment: I'd check that _before_ going into the loop. Then you check only once. If you do it inside the loop, you need to perform _some_ check n times (where n is array length).

Answer (score 0):

> How to apply code to only first iteration of loop

I suggest using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for this task following way

```
for inx, track in enumerate(json['TrackConditionHistory']):
    if inx == 0:
        raceno = track['RaceNumber']
    if not raceno == 1:
        trackcondition = json['TrackCondition']
    else:
        trackcondition = track['TrackConditionRating']
```

This way `raceno` will be changed solely in first turn of loop.

Comment: The issue with this code is that it doesn't record the 'TrackConditionRating' for Race 6 as per the example. I need a code that looks at the first iteration and then decides whether to proceed collecting data in a particular way or collect different data.

Answer (score 0):

While Daweo's answer works, if you have a big json file to parse you'll have to check that if condition for every loop iteration. What you can do instead is:

```py
raceno = json['TrackConditionHistory'][0]['RaceNumber']

for track in json['TrackConditionHistory'][1:]:
    if not raceno == 1:
        trackcondition = json['TrackCondition']
    else:
        trackcondition = track['TrackConditionRating']
```

Also if `raceno == 1` then you don't make use of the `track` at all in the loop so there's not really a reason for it to be inside the loop. Simply use the loop when `raceno == 1`, or don't use it at all.

As for the behavior type, you're only adding an entry to your data after the loop is completed, hence you only get the last values encountered in the loop.

So combining the initial race number check placed before the loop, and correcting the loop itself, we get the following full example:

test.json file:

```json
{
   "TrackConditionHistory":[
      {
         "RaceNumber":1,
         "TrackConditionRatingSourceNumber":8,
         "TrackCondition":"Heavy",
         "TrackConditionRating":"Heavy 8",
         "TrackConditionRatingSource":8,
         "TrackConditionSource":5
      },
      {
         "RaceNumber":6,
         "TrackConditionRatingSourceNumber":9,
         "TrackCondition":"Heavy",
         "TrackConditionRating":"Heavy 9",
         "TrackConditionRatingSource":9,
         "TrackConditionSource":5
      }
   ]
}
```

python file:

```py
import json

data = []

with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    json = json.load(f)


firstraceno = json['TrackConditionHistory'][0]['RaceNumber']

if firstraceno == 1:
    for track in json['TrackConditionHistory']:
        raceno = track["RaceNumber"]
        trackcondition = track["TrackConditionRating"]
        data.append((raceno, trackcondition))


print(data)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'Heavy 8'), (6, 'Heavy 9')]
```

Note that I don't what `meetcode` is, and I had to complete the json sample to make it valid.

Comment: This does not work as the line 'raceno = json['TrackConditionHistory']['RaceNumber']' produces an error saying list indicies must be intergers not strings

Comment: I forget an index, just edited it

Comment: I get list index out of range using that index.

Comment: I tested it, it works properly with the input you've given.

Comment: Ok i went too fast above the title of the question. Let me take another look